# Change material of hidden elements of Autodesk Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would like to change material (THREE.MeshPhongMaterial) of elements which were hidden by the viewer. The default hidden elements are still visible, but I want to change their transparency and color.

Here is the example code. I tried to change both theming color and material but no success:

```
viewer.hideById(dbId);

var color = 0x0000ff; // blue color
viewer.setThemingColor(dbId, color, viewer.model);

var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
var fragmentList = viewer.model.getFragmentList();

instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, function (fragId) {
    fragmentList.setMaterial(fragId, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { opacity: 0.5 } ));
});

viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
```

However, nothing is changed after updating materials of hidden elements. How to fix that. I want my custom hidden elements with different colors and transparency.

Comment: what do you expect to change when the element is hidden? the properties?

Comment: When the element is hidden, I can exclude it out of the selection of other elements. However, I want different color and transparency of hidden elements. They are still visible on the viewer, but have different color and transparency depending on their properties.

Comment: do you mean change color os transparent/ghost elements? because when you hide them, it will be completely hidden (no color/material visible)

Comment: You are right. I want to change color and opacity of transparent/ghost elements. The reason is to exclude them out of selection set, and make them look different depending on their categories. Then I can pick through the ghost element to select its inner elements.

Comment: got it, let me research that for you.

Comment: sorry but, as of now, it's not possible to select through elements on transparent/ghost mode (from your last comment here)

Comment: var vp = _viewer.impl.clientToViewport(event.canvasX, event.canvasY);
        var renderer = _viewer.impl.renderer();

        var dbId = renderer.idAtPixel(vp.x, vp.y);

Comment: I see we can select through elements on transparent/ghost mode with `viewer.impl.renderer().idAtPixel(x, y)`. Please see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265736/picking-under-elements-of-an-element-in-autodesk-forge-viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Forge Viewer, if you hide an object, as Augusto mentioned, it seems that the object will be completely hidden, you can not set the material to see it as you want. But, there is a trick workaround may help to achieve what you did with Three.js in http://app.netonapp.com/JavaScript/Three.js/select_inner_objects.html, you can select the inside object, and still can see the outside "hidden" object.

What I did is simple, within the callback function of “mousedown" event, the first thing I did is to set the outside object hidden by API viewer.hideById(dbId), then to select the object by your API viewer.impl.renderer().idAtPixel. In this case, it will ignore the hidden object and just select the inside object. And in the function of “SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT” event, I added the code viewer.show(dbid) to show the outside object.

By this way, you can set the material as you want for the outside object, the outside object will be shown as other normal objects, but it will be just hidden for a while when you try to select object. The solution seems working on my side, but I did not test it thoroughly, you can try to see if it works.

Comment: It seems to be a very smart solution. Thank you Zhong Wu. I will test it.

Comment: I got the final solution. I will wrap it as a new viewer extension and post the answer later.

Comment: Please see the complete working code at the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265736/picking-under-elements-of-an-element-in-autodesk-forge-viewer/41373450#41373450